# HTML Footer on my website

Tags: html

I'm working on a website: [Click here](http://www.mattowebdesign.nl/alexandra)

On every page I made a footer. But I can't get the footer centered and locked on the bottom of the page. Hope some of you guys can help me. I already tried some stuff I found on StackOverflow but it won't work....

Regards,

Matthijs

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Links to a site with a "fix my code" message will get closed. Take a look here to find out how to ask a good question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . You need to create a Minimal, Complete, Valid Example, and show what you have tried in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class you are using on the div (`.grid_4`) has a `float:left` value. If you get rid of this float and you add `text-align: center` on the div, the content is centered.

For a sticky footer, check out [this link](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html)

Comment: Thnx! That solved my problem!